# AJAX POST and Plus ( + ) and (&) Sign How to Encode?

Tags: php, ajax, post, decode, encode

I'm POSTing the contents of a form field via `AJAX to a PHP script` and using this code

```
if(!http)
            http = CreateObject();  

        nocache = Math.random();

        http.open('post', 'addvm.php');
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        http.onreadystatechange = SaveReply;

        http.send(params);
```

The problem is that any `+ and &` signs are being stripped out and replaced. How can I safely 'encode' the `+ and &` signs and then appropriately 'decode' it on the PHP side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need to encode your params `encodeURIComponent`
Note:-When you access `$_GET, $_POST or $_REQUEST in PHP`, you are retrieving values that have already been decoded.

Answer (score 1):

try:

js: `encodeURIComponent (/* url */);`

php: `urldecode (/* url */);`

Comment: just change the last line of your code to this:

http.send(encodeURIComponent(params)); // and then catch it on your server with urldecode if you wish...

Comment: try this in your php script witch handles the post request:

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = urldecode($value);

and you'll have it all decoded in the $_POST

Comment: check it out here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp, and see the Try It Yourself!, and this aswell: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: @metaforce : see bro i want to decode to my password only $password = $_POST["password"]; what i can do here

Comment: @ metaforce: not working http.send(encodeURIComponent(params));